# removing first tab before window shows

Tags: c#, wpf, tabs

Hi i currently have a window that has a tab control. What i am trying to do is remove the tab that is first created by my xaml then call my c# code that creates a new tab.

Currently i have

```
public MainWindow()   
        {
            InitializeComponent();
             newTab();                
             tabControl1.Items.Remove(tabControl1.SelectedValue="tabItem1");
        }
```

The first tab has the value "tabItem1" but it doesn't seem to remove the tab. I have also tried doing a remove on index 0 but that didn't work either.

Thanks!

Comment: erm ... if you don't want that tab ... why not just removing it from the XAML code?

Comment: i initialize some things based on it.. i know its weird how i have it set up but i need to remove it after initialize componet but before it gets shown

Comment: maybe you want to have a look at the MVVM pattern ... it could save you from the code behind hell ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are sure that you want to do it this way... give the tabItem a name, and remove it by using its reference ...

```
<TabControl Name="tabControl1" >
    <TabItem Header="tabItem1" Name="tabItem1">
        <Grid />
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="tabItem2" Name="tabItem2">
        <Grid />
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

and remove the Tab with:

```
tabControl1.Items.Remove(tabItem1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Give Remove() whatever the x:Name of the TabItem object is:

```
public MainWindow()   
{
    InitializeComponent();
    newTab();                
    tabControl1.Items.Remove(tabItem1);
}
```